# JPA managed entity throwing null pointer exception

Tags: hibernate, jpa, nullpointerexception, thread-safety

I am using JPA 2.0 along with SpringBoot for one of my projects. Since the application required lots of read-only queries, I decided to make a singleton (Autowired) class with entityManager marked as 
**@PersistenceContext(type=PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)**.

This same instance of the extended entity manager was in turn used by the numerous DAOs (perhaps in multiple threads) for their read only requests. Since the entities used to be within the extended persistence context, the calls to further elaborate (hydrate, if you will) on the entity never gave LazyInitializationException. Also, since the entities, once loaded, were always present in the active memory of the extended persistence context one used to get excellent performance.

However, with passing time I occasionally started getting **NullPointerException** while accessing one of the fields of one of the managed entities. The behaviour was non-deterministic.

```
        // .. earlier code skipped for brevity
        Child child = refNode.getFirstChild();

        if (child != null) {
            // Print confirms that the object is managed. In fact, earlier merely 
            // inserting print statement would dissolve the error.
            System.out.printf ("Child ID = %s %s\n", child.getChildID(), childDAO.getContext(child));

            // NPE while accessing latestVersion attribute of 'Child'.
            // Values does exist in DB. 
            Unode un = child.getLatestVersion().getuNode();
            return un;
        }
```

The relevant portion of 'Child' entity is as follows:

```
    public class Child implements Serializable { 
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
        private int childID;
        ...
        @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
        @JoinColumn(name="latestVersionID")
        private Version latestVersion;
```

And yes, I also received the following error quite generously.

```
    HHH000099: an assertion failure occured (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session): org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: possible non-threadsafe access to the session
```

Of late I am also getting 'ConcurrentModificationException', unsafe thread accesss, and similar errors in all sort of hitherto clean portions of the code. I also tried making my extended context entity manager thread safe using synchronized(mutex) at all access, but of no help.

My biggest worry is a managed entity (in extended context) giving null pointed exception. Though the exceptions appear non-deterministically they appear to be often centered around places where 'Child' or 'Child.LatestVersion' is accessed.

I tried, Lazy Loading, Eager Loading etc., but of no use. My understanding (upto this point) was that forward entities are loaded eagerly, reverse entities lazily, and never a null pointed exception when the entity is managed (in whichever context - extended or transactional).

Any help would be sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is rather simple: `EntityManager` is not thread-safe. See e.g. here: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-basics-issues

What you should do is you should stop trying to reuse it. The `EntityManager` is (in contrast to `EntityManagerFactory`) inexpensive to create.

Comment: Crizzis, thanks. The extended entity manager is used only for read only queries as the persistence context works as an excellent cache. No update/insert operations are performed using the extended em. Moreover, accessing em through DI should make it thread safe anyway (though thread safety is not required for read only requests), isn't it? Moreover, thread safe or not, should managed entity ever through null pointer exception?

Comment: If you're using a non thread-safe object from multiple threads, it's not going to be thread-safe. I can't see how DI is supposed to solve that problem. Also thread safety is about whether the *internal implementation* of `EntityManager` is thread-sensitive or not, whether it is thread-safe to use with read-only requests is a question for the `Hibernate` folks. Finally, if you're using an API in a way you're not supposed to, no one can guarantee what should or shouldn't ever happen

Comment: Also, if you have one shared cache for entities retrieved through reads, you do realize that write operations that do not 'go' through that cache will make it go out of sync? Perhaps you should consider using 2nd level cache: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkjio.html

Comment: Thanks again. Reading one of the earlier posts I was under the impression the spring also guarantees thread safety for its singletons. Anyway, I synchronized the em access using mutex, without much benefit through. Yes, I agree that it is the Hibernate guys who alone can tell whether read only requests are thread safe. And yes, I am aware that the cache would become dirty if the data is updated from elsewhere. I am taking care of that by flushing the em periodically. The second level cache (I used ehcache) doesn't work that well as it serializes the entity and reconstructs java object from it.

Comment: I am pretty sure ehcache can be configured to use in-memory cache only

Comment: Well, in that case I may have been trying to reinvent the wheel :)